# Почему не устанавливается setValue() в NumberPicker?

Tags: java, android

У меня есть диапазон значений и нужно, чтоб по умолчанию `NumberPicker` был в середине своих значений...

я вот делаю это так

```
NumberPicker pickerHeight = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.pickerHeight);
    pickerHeight.setMaxValue(220);
    pickerHeight.setMinValue(130);
    pickerHeight.setValue(155);
```

В последней строчке указываю значение по умолчанию.
Но когда загружаю на девайс, то все равно по умолчанию значение стоит на самой нижней отметке в моем случае на 130.

Что делаю не так?

Comment: А если вот это добавить? `pickerHeight.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);`?

Comment: Нет эта строчка просто не дает `NumberPicker` вращаться по кругу и как только он доходит до одного из предельных значений по `min` или `max`, то дальше значений нет... Причем тоже странно на одном `NumberPicker` это так работает, а на другом это просто игнорится и ничего не происходит... Хотя одно и тоже, что там, что там...

Comment: Т.е. если создать пустой проект с пустым активити и в ней только вот один пикер указать в разметке и над ним приведённые вами операции произвести то ничего не заработает? Или вы скрываете таки какие-то детали?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб В общем такая ситуация, создал чистый проект, поставил в него пикер, сделал все как обговорили и все получилось... Попробовал на основном проекте еще раз и ничего не получилось(сделал все один в один), потом я удалил приложение с телефона и установил еще раз и все получилось... Очень странно... мне кажется это из за новой студии 2.1, она вроде как не всегда код обновляет а только XML файлы... Ну мне так кажется...

Comment: Ну, возможно как раз в новой студии и дело - они ж там обещали менять UI без перезапуска приложения на девайсе... Вот из-за таких не очень понятных штук я пока и не тороплюсь с 1.5 обновляться))

Comment: Ну и напишите это в ответ - может кому-то пригодится и вопрос не будет неотвеченным висеть)

Answer (score 1):

В общем такая ситуация, создал чистый проект, поставил в него пикер,

```
<NumberPicker
                    android:id="@+id/pickerWeight"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

Потом установил минимум максимум и значение по умолчанию вот так

```
NumberPicker pickerHeight = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.pickerHeight);
    pickerHeight.setMaxValue(220);
    pickerHeight.setMinValue(130);
    pickerHeight.setValue(155);
```

и все получилось... Попробовал на основном проекте еще раз и ничего не получилось(сделал все один в один). Потом я удалил приложение с телефона и установил еще раз и все получилось... Очень странно... мне кажется это из за новой студии 2.1, она вроде как не всегда код обновляет а только XML файлы... Ну мне так кажется...